# Splitting the first column of a file in multiple columns using AWK

Tags: linux, unix, awk, split

File looks like this, but with millions of lines (`TAB` separated):

```
1_number_column_ranking_+   100 200 Target "Hello"
```

I want to split the first column by the `_` so it becomes:

```
1 number column ranking + 100 200 Target "Hello"
```

This is the code I have been trying:

```
awk -F"\t" '{n=split($1,a,"_");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1"\t"a[i]}'
```

But it's not quite what I need.
Any help is appreciated (the other threads on this topic were not helpful for me).

Comment: If `_` can occur anywhere else in your file then include that in your sample input and output because otherwise `tr '_' '\t' < file` is all you need.

Comment: In your sample input, should all occurrences of whitespace be interpreted as tabs, or does that first line have TWO fields, one with underscores and the other with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

No need to split, just replace would do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{gsub("_","\t",$1)}1'
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file
1_number_column_ranking_+       100     200     Target "Hello"

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{gsub("_","\t",$1)}1' file
1       number  column  ranking +       100     200     Target "Hello"
```

`gsub` will replace all occurances, when no 3rd argument given, it will replace in $0.
Last `1` is a shortcut for `{print}`. (always `true`, implied `{print}`.)

Answer (score 2):

Another awk, if the "_" appears only in the first column. 
Split the input field by regex "[_\t]+" and just do a dummy operation like $1=$1 in the main section, so that $0 is reconstructed with OFS="\t"

```
$ cat steveman.txt
1_number_column_ranking_+       100     200i    Target  "Hello"

$ awk -F"[_\t]" ' BEGIN { OFS="\t"} { $1=$1; print } ' steveman.txt
1       number  column  ranking +       100     200i    Target  "Hello"

$
```

Thanks @Ed, updated from `-F"[_\t]+"` to `-F"[_\t]"` that will avoid concatenating empty fields.